# Getting error: variable private acces in Component

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm stuck at this error, 'name has a private access in Component'. I don't understand what it means, but I think I may have wrongly initialized the variable 'name' in the main method. The error points inside the startGame() method, where I initialized 'label1'.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gamey extends JFrame
{
private JPanel panelUp;
private JPanel panelDown;
private JButton btnPlay, btnNext;
private JLabel label1;

public Gamey()
{
    super("Game");
    startGame();
}

public void startGame()
{
    Container c = getContentPane();
    panelUp = new JPanel();
    panelDown = new JPanel();
    label1 = new JLabel(name + "Snow glows white on the mountain tonight");  //name has a private access in Component
    btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
    btnNext = new JButton("Next");

    btnPlay.addActionListener(new Handler());

    panelUp.add(label1);
    panelDown.add(btnPlay);

    c.add(panelUp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c.add(panelDown, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


}

public class Handler implements ActionListener
{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == btnPlay)
        {
            btnPlay.setText("Next");
            label1.setText("Not a footprint to be seen");

        }

    }

}




public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter name: ");
    Gamey game = new Gamey();

    game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.setSize(450,450);
    game.setVisible(true);
    game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Gamey` extend the [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class which in-turn extend the [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) class. In the method `startGame()`, you have used a field called `name` in this statement.

```
label1 = new JLabel(name + "Snow glows white on the mountain tonight");
```

Since there is no instance variable by that name in your `Gamey` class, it has gone up the hierarchy to check for such a field and found one present in the `Component` class. But this field `name` has the `private` access modifier and that is why you're getting the error

```
name has a private access in Component.
```

To get rid of this error, either declare a `name` field in your `Gamey` class or in the `startGame()` depending on your requirements.

*Note:* Your code is bit jumbled but I could see that you're having a variable `name` in the `main()` method. You can make it an instance variable, and populate its value in the `main()` method which can then be used in the `startGame()` method. Something like this:

```
public class Gamey extends JFrame {
    // Other fields
    private String name;
    // Getter & setter for name

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gamey game = new Gamey();
        game.setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter name: ")); // Set the name with the value from the input dialog
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I have followed your suggestion. Thanks! But here's another one. It compiled but the name variable displayed null, like this: nullSnow glows white on the mountain tonight. Why does it do that?